# カラムやバリデーションに引っかかったcsvファイルのエラーがエラー画面に出てしまいます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

現在、csvファイルを作成しており、画像のようにファイルを選択してボタンを押すとcsvファイルがインポートできる機能を実装しております。
無事にインポートできたのですが、１度取り込んだcsvファイルを再びインポートすると、画像のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
３時間以上詰まってしまったので、解決策を教えていただけると幸いです。

○実現したいこと→エラーを解消したい
○現状→同じcsvファイルをインポートすると写真のようなエラーがでる（初回のインポートは問題なくできる）
○試みたこと→保存されたカラムの重複と考えたので、rails:db:migerate:resetをし、再度インポート。

お忙しい中お手数おかけしますが、宜しくお願い致します。

[image: エラー画面]

[image: ブラウザ画面]

＊users_controller＊

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

＊user.rb＊

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

＊index.thml.erb＊

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ソースコードはキャプチャ画像ではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。

Comment: 承知いたしました。ご指摘いただき、ありがとううございます

Comment: エラーが出ることが問題のように質問に書いてあるようですが、実際はテーブルのユニーク制約で同じEmailが登録できないようになっているようです。エラーが解消させるためにユニーク制約をはずしたいのですか？一度テーブル設計とアプリの仕様を検討したほうが良いと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ユニークはそのままで行い、引っかかった場合に、flashなどで重複を伝えたいのですが、一度見直すこととします。